# Matplotlib dataframe with one y axis value not showing correctly in plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data frame

```
dftemp1
Out[507]: 
   level  time
0   14.0   0.0
1   14.0   0.5
2   14.0   1.0
3   14.0   1.5
4   14.0   2.0
5   14.0   2.5
6   14.0   3.0
7   14.0   3.5
8   14.0   4.0

dftemp1.level.dtype
Out[509]: dtype('float64')

dftemp1.plot(x = 'time', y = 'level', kind = 'scatter', title = 'level vs time')
```

When I plot it, the y-axis is completely off. I can't figure out why. It should read 14.0

[image: plot of dftemp1]

Comment: The plot is fine, just the values on the y-axis are displayed in an unusual way for some reason. There is a mark above the top edge `+1.399e1` which indicates that one needs to add 13.99 to each y-axis label.

Comment: @bb1 Is there a way to change that? It's very odd that it defaulted to that.

Comment: I am not sure, I cannot reproduce this issue. You can try to specify format of the ticks labels: `ax = plt.subplot(111)`  `dftemp1.plot(x='time', y='level', kind='scatter', title='level vs time', ax=ax)`  `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:.1f}'))` These are three lines, there is no way of arranging the code properly in comments.

Comment: By the way, what version of pandas are you running? The latest is 1.1.5. Does the problem still occur with the latest version?

Comment: I tried to update all libraries and now matplotlib causes kernel catastrophic failure.